# Number of square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ complex matrices. What is upper bound for the number solutions to $B^2=A$ if you know that is finite for a given matrix $A$.

The solutions are given here [Linear Algebra: 2004 September: Problem 1](http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Linear_Algebra:_2004_September:_Problem_1), but is not understandble. First of all what is the order of $N$?

Comment: The (nilpotence) order of $N$ here is the smallest exponent $m$ with $N^m=0$. Try to understand the proof there yourself.

Comment: So is it a theorem that we can write $A$ as $A=\lambda I+N$?

Comment: The theorem is the Jordan normal form. We may assume WLOG that  $A$ has only one Jordan block, so that $A=\lambda I+N$.